# Bracket in `description` item throws error

Tags: brackets, description

Closing bracket in math mode causes error in `description` item and leaves a space in text mode.  What can I do?

This gives error

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[$[0,1]$] 
\end{description}
\end{document}

l.6 \end{description}
                     
? 
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.6 \end{description}
                     
?
```

And this code leaves a space before the closing bracket

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[[0,1]] 
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: space before bracket]

Comment: you have `\item[$[0,1]` so the argument has an unclosed math mode, use `\item[{$[0,1]$}]`

Comment: Thanks @davidcarlisle, even if I close the math mode, I get error, but yeah, what you suggest works and makes sense.

Comment: you wouldn't get an error if you close the math before the `]` unlike `{}` tex does not match `[]`  the argument for `\item` (and all classical latex optional arguments) ends at the first `]`

Comment: I am not sure, I understand: I do have `\item[$[0,1]$]` not `\item[$[0,1]]`, so I thought I did close the math mode, and I still get error about missing $.    The label stands for the 0-1 closed interval. But I'll use grouping from now on...

Comment: @campa, for me the surprise was that closing math mode still throws error.  The example you linked to is not about math mode.

Comment: I now get it, @campa, though the linked answer is way over my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classical LaTeX optional arguments (defined in the format, or via `\newcommand`)
do not pair matching `[..]` the argument ends at the first `]`

so

You have `\item[$[0,1]`  so the argument `$[0,1`  has an unclosed math mode, use `\item[{$[0,1]$}]`

Your second example is similar, you get no error but `\item[[0,1]]`   is an `\item` with optional argument specifying a label of `[0,1`  and the start of the item text being `]`, you would want `\item[{[0,1]}]` so the optional argument was `[0,1]`

Comment: So a second $ in itself doesn't close math mode, as in `\item[$[0,1]$]`.  Got it.

Comment: @MátéWierdl tex never reaches the second $ as it typesets the label `$[0,1` so throws a missing `$` error, if you try to scroll that it will auto-add a `$` to force close the math, so then the `$]` at the start of the item tex will _start_ a new unwanted math group and put all the following text in math mode.